# is there any api for linux iptables , so that my program can add firewall rules

Tags: c, linux, gcc, iptables, libc

I am writing an application using libc,
for that  am in search of an api for iptables 
 so that i can add firewall rules using my program .is there any available set of api to do this.

Comment: why not use a script ?

Comment: @0A0D its diffcult for quering firewall rules , if they exists

Answer (score 5):

You can use libiptc

Quote from the howto page:

> libiptc is the library that is used to communicate with netfilter, the internal kernel code in charge of firewalling and packet filtering. This code and iptables were written by Paul "Rusty" Russell. iptables was developed using libiptc calls to get the job done.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Querying-libiptc-HOWTO/whatis.html

Comment: See also http://www.bani.com.br/lang/en/2012/05/programmatically-managing-iptables-rules-in-c-iptc/

Comment: `libiptc` seems to be pretty outdated with latest release 20 years ago.